# DRF : CreateAPIView - UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django Rest Framework with React for the front.
I want to post Note linked to a ForeignKey User.

**models.Note**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

**serializers.NoteSerializer**

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('user', 'content')
```

When I post `{user: 1, content: "test"}`, I get the following error message:

`UNIQUE constraint failed: app_note.user_id`

How can I link the new Note to an existing user, posting the user.id?

I think my current code is trying to create a new User Instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using OneToOneField in Note model. That means a user can have only one note.
use ForeignKey instead to have many notes for single user.